# why the var cannot be reassign?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, var, let

I debug this function, I found the var **indexOfString** cannot update after finding one index, why?

```
function occurrencesOfSubstring(fullString, substring){
    var countOfString = 0
    var indexOfString = 0
    while(true){
        indexOfString = fullString.indexOf(substring,indexOfString)
        if (indexOfString > 0){
            countOfString += 1
        }else{
            return countOfString
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To be clear, you aren't getting an error saying that the variable can't be reassigned, but are wondering why it isn't changing?

Comment: @Teemu where should I put?

Comment: @Teemu no thats not the issue. the OP didnt really post what the problem was.

Comment: It returns alway undefined, yeas?

Comment: You need to update `indexOfString` by at least one after each successful match else it will never change.

Comment: @RobM. Yes, it will loop infinitely

Comment: `if (indexOfString > 0){` What if `indexOfString` returns `0`? If you step through your code while running and examine the variables, it'll be easier to find the flawed logic.

Comment: If you will have at least one occurency, you will never break the loop.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp how to update?

Comment: @Vitalii no return, it'll always loop

Comment: @spanky what if >=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
var indexOfString = -1;
...
    indexOfString = fullString.indexOf(substring,indexOfString + 1);
```

Otherwise, you keep finding the same index every time you go through the loop.

Also, remember that indexes are zero-based, so if the "first" character of the string starts a match for your substring, you'll get `0` as the result. So you could change your conditional to this:

```
    if (indexOfString >= 0){
        countOfString += 1
    }else{
        return countOfString
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you guys, I know where the problem is.

```
function occurrencesOfSubstring(fullString, substring){
    var countOfString = 0
    var indexOfString = 0
    while(true){
        indexOfString = fullString.indexOf(substring,indexOfString + 1)
        if (indexOfString > 0){
            countOfString += 1
        }else{
            return countOfString
        }
    }
}
```